# i'm trying to run node server.js but i'm told Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\node\backend\server.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
S C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\node\backend> node server.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\node\backend\server.js'
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
PS C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\node\backend> node server.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\node\backend\server.js'
PS C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\node\backend> node server.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\node\backend\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

i'm getting the above error whenever im running node server.js i've severally run npm install but all has been in vain

```
const express = require("express")
var app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (_req, res) =>{
    res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`server is running on port number ${port}`)
})
```

I expected the terminal to console server is running on port number 3000
I installed `express` but i'm being told `MODULE NOT FOUND`

Comment: can you show your package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and should run, given that you used e.g. `npm init -y` and `npm install express` before. I suppose `npm start` gives you the same error?

Other than that, it seems that your code is in a folder that synchronises with OneDrive... are you certain that it is properly synchronized? Have you tried to display the contents of server.js with e.g. `more server.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether the `node_modules` folder is in the same directory as the current project file. If not, place the project file on the directory of `node_modules`. If you face the same error, reinstall the required node modules and run the file.